# Getcontext() apply to the elements of the array with structs

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

```
typedef struct _ut_slot {
   ucontext_t uc;
   ....
}*ut_slot;

static ut_slot*  table;  //array of the structs

void foo (int tab_size){
     table =  malloc ( tab_size *(sizeof (ut_slot))); // memory allocation for array of structs 
     for(i = 0 ; i < tab_size ; i++  ){
        getcontext(&table[i].uc); <--- ?????? 
      }
}
```

I receive error in "getcontext" string. How can I write reference to any element of the  array? And how can I initialize with "getcontext" command the "uc" field of each array element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an inconsistency with the definition of `ut_slot` and the use of it:

```
typedef struct _ut_slot {
   ucontext_t uc;
   ....
}*ut_slot; //<--- pointer to struct
```

You say that `ut_slot` is a pointer to a struct, then you declare

> static ut_slot*  table;

so you have a pointer-to-pointer-to-struct.

You probably want `ut_slot` to just be a struct, or `table` to be a pointer-to-struct.

---

To be more precise: `table` is a pointer-to-pointer-to-struct, so `table[i]` is a pointer-to-struct, and you try to access a struct member of a non-struct with `table[i].ut`, which raises a compilation error.

---

Try the following:

```
typedef struct _ut_slot {
   ucontext_t uc;
   ....
} ut_slot; //removed "*"

static ut_slot *table;
```

the rest of your code is okay and doesn't need to be changed.

Comment: I edit my comment. How can I access the uc field in a right way?

Comment: I get that you explained. It worked now:  getcontext(&(*table[i]).uc));

Comment: @TatianaCooper Wait, your malloc call is wrong because sizeof(ut_slot) is the size of a pointer (just about 4 bytes) instead the size of the struct - use the solution I edited in

Answer (score 0):

The manual for getcontext puts forth a prototype like this:

```
int getcontext(ucontext_t *ucp);
```

Are you sure you are passing it the right argument? ;)

If you realy want an array of structs you have to set aside some memory for each.
Notice how -> dereferences the pointer and & gets the address of the member struct. It's confusing and looks backwards.

Sorry, I program without curly brackets and punctuation. Anchor C adds them automatically.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
typedef struct _ut_slot
    ucontext_t uc
    ...
*ut_slot
static ut_slot *table
int main  void
    static ucontext_t uc
    table = malloc  1 * sizeof ut_slot
    table[0] = malloc  sizeof *ut_slot
    getcontext  &table[0]->uc
    free  table[0]
    free  table
    return 0
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem. I want to pass the us field of array element and I don't know how to write it.

Comment: thanks! I had "Segmentation fault" error before I changed as you said.